# Applying conservation of energy to a railgun problem?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, classical-electrodynamics

When a projectile is lunched due to the Lorentz force($F_L$), how can I apply the conservation of energy that the electrical energy inputted to generate the Lorentz force & magnetic field equals the kinetic energy of the projectile(ignoring dissipated losses).

In fact, to any problem where there is a wire accelerated due to the Lorentz force in a uniform magnetic field?

Answer (score 2):

You can do so.  The energy put in is the integral of $VI$, the product of the voltage and current.  It may be hard to calculate $I$ from $V$ because of the back emf and changing circuit resistance.  The energy absorbed is the increasing magnetic field energy caused by the expansion of the current loop and the increasing kinetic energy of the wire and projectile. Ignoring losses, these should be equal.

Comment: Why would it be an integral? Is it due to the varying voltage input to maintain motion with the back emf's opposition? Supplying a higher voltage to maintain the current constant? Why would the magnetic field's energy expand? Assuming it's a uniform one? Finally, why would the back-emf change the resistance of the circuit? Not sure how to model the energy conversions as well, it's electrical energy to kinetic energy directly? Where does the magnetic field energy come into play with the energy conversions?

Comment: It is an integral if you do not assume $V,I$ constant. If they are, you can just multiply $VIt$ to get the power input.  I don't know how constant either one is.  The magnetic field energy expands because it is the integral of $B^2$ over all space (with some constants).  The increasing size of the loop makes that increase.  The back-emf comes into the relationship of $V$ and $I$.  As I said, the conversion is electrical energy in to the combination of kinetic and magnetic field energy out.

Comment: The kinetic energy makes perfect sense, however, I'm struggling with the idea that there is energy stored in the magnetic field?

Comment: Ow, do you mean the magnetic field of the conductor itself acting like an inductor?

Comment: Exactly.  Any current distribution acts as an inductor.  It creates a magnetic field that contains energy.  Normally the energy contained in the field is small enough to be neglected, but in a railgun the current is very high.